# Does number of hardlinks to a directory correspond to the number of subdirectories in it?

Tags: unix, filesystems, hardlink

When displaying directories using `ls -l`, their number of links (the second field in the output) is at least two: one for the dir name and one for `.`

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 user   wheel  512  4 oct 14:02 foo
```

Is it safe to always assume that the number of links above 2 corresponds to the number of subdirectories in this dir (`..` links) ?

Comment: why not use something like `ls -d1 */ | wc -l`    That'll also take into account links, if thats what you want.

Comment: @Sirex: it's just curiosity, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While generally you can only use symbolic links to directories, which will not affect the link count, there are some circumstances where hard-links are possible for directories (IIRC OSX's TimeMachine feature uses such links) so it might not always be guaranteed.

You would be safer passing a scan using `ls` and `grep` (or perhaps `find`) to the `wc` command to count the number of sub-directories actually present rather than trying to guess from the current directories link count.

Comment: I don't understand - unless you use the -i flag to compare the results, ls won't find any duplicates.  That being said, I've never encountered multiple hardlinks to directories (disregarding . and ..) and I'm highly surprised that some tool should use them by design.  I wouldn't be surprised if standard tools such as find, ls -R and tar assume this property to hold.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to observe that all directories contain . and .., so if you subtract two from the output of

```
ls -la | grep '^d' | wc -l
```

you should get the number of directories in your current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

this does not answer your question about ls -l, but I use tree -d for this, it works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would use find

```
find ./foo -type d | wc -l
```

eventually with the `-maxdepth` option